setting triggers and calling POST api on any change in a node or a relation in neo4j DB using apoc
I have been trying to setup trigger to monitor any change in a node or a relation in my neo4j DB, also that updated node or relation data should be send as request body to an external POST api.
So far i have been able to make an POST api call on any change in db, also API endpoints are being called, but i want to put the trigger condition on a specific type of node or relation. also i am not able to get what data was updated and send it as request body. The neo4j's apoc documentation are not very clear to me.
here's structure of a very basic trigger which calls my POST api endpoint whenever any data change(insert, update, delete) happens in my db, and sends "testkey=testvalue"
CALL apoc.trigger.add(
  'dbchangetrigger',
  "CALL apoc.load.jsonParams('http://192.168.1.122:9500/api/trigger/triggerFromDb',{method: 'POST'},'testkey=testvalue')",
  {phase: 'after'}
);

i want this trigger to happen when a particular type of node is updated and that updated data should be send to the api

apoc.trigger.add is deprecated. You can find some documentation on triggers in general here, which includes an example of how to use apoc.trigger.install to capture node property settings from the $assignedNodeProperties parameter. Your use case is a lot bigger and would require special processing for almost every parameter provided to your trigger Cypher query. Hopefully the doc will get you started.
